# Convert object to array, insert value between array indexes

Tags: javascript

I have one question I send form from client to server and get object which checkbox is true and here is problem. e.g. `'0': true, '3':true` and I would like that my array looks `[true,false,false,true]`, but now I get array like this `[true, true]` I use `map`. So in short between object `true` i would insert `false`. Please look on my code:

```
var correctAns = [];
var quizCorrectAnswer = 
    { '0': { '0': true },
      '1': { '0': true, '3': true },
      '2': { '2': true } 
     }
for(correct in quizCorrectAnswer){
  correctAns.push(Object.keys(quizCorrectAnswer[correct]).map((k) => 
  quizCorrectAnswer[correct][k]))
}
```

I would like receive following arrays: `0: [true], 1: [true, false, false, true], 2: [false, false, true]` but now I get `0: [true], 1: [true, true], 2: [true]`

Comment: @NinaScholz The last is `[false, false, true]` in his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```js
var correctAns = {};
var quizCorrectAnswer = 
    { '0': { '0': true },
      '1': { '0': true, '3': true },
      '2': { '2': true } 
     }
     
Object.keys(quizCorrectAnswer).forEach((question) => {
  correctAns[question] = Object.keys(quizCorrectAnswer[question]).reduce((prev, key) => {
    while (prev.length < key) {
      prev.push(false);
    }
    prev.push(true);
    return prev;
  }, []);
});

console.log(correctAns);
```

If you want `correctAns` to simply be an array, use this instead:

```js
var quizCorrectAnswer = 
    { '0': { '0': true },
      '1': { '0': true, '3': true },
      '2': { '2': true } 
     }
     
var correctAns = Object.keys(quizCorrectAnswer).map((question) => {
  return Object.keys(quizCorrectAnswer[question]).reduce((prev, key) => {
    while (prev.length < key) {
      prev.push(false);
    }
    prev.push(true);
    return prev;
  }, []);
});

console.log(correctAns);
```

Comment: You could replace forEach with map to tidy this up :)

Comment: const myO = {a:1,b:2}; const myA = Object.keys(myO).map((i) => myO[i]). Then myA will be an array. It's FRP so you can maintain a 'pure function'

Comment: @sidhuko Took your suggestion for the second code snippet. Don't think it's possible in the second one (easily, without crazy es6 modifiers, or something like underscore.js) to keep the keys as is with mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you map the keys which return an array with only the given answers. But you need an array with the holes and their false values.

To iterate a sparse array with an array method, you need to convert it into an array without sparse elements and then map a boolean value.

```js
var quizCorrectAnswer = { 0: { 0: true }, 1: { 0: true, 3: true }, 2: { 2: true } },
    correctAns = [],
    correct,
    temp;
    
for (correct in quizCorrectAnswer) {
    temp = [];

    Object
        .keys(quizCorrectAnswer[correct])
        .forEach(k => temp[k] = quizCorrectAnswer[correct][k])

    correctAns.push(Array.apply(null, temp).map(Boolean));
}

console.log(correctAns);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const result = {};
  for(const [key, obj] of Object.entries(quizCorrectAnswer))
     result[key] = Array.from({...obj, length:5}, el => !!el);
```

You could use `Array.from` to convert the object into an array. Instead of the static length of `5`, you could also take `Object.keys(obj).length`

Answer (score -1):

That's the problem of non-appeared keys and values.
Here in `quizCorrectAnswer` variable value about key '1', there are only '0' and '3' keys.
No '1' or '2' key and value is defined in that value.
And Javascript `map` function matches the existing keys to values and so you can get only `[true, true]` about '1' key (because there are only 2 keys in that value).
So to get the result you want, you have to change the `quizCorrectAnswer` value as follows.

```
var quizCorrectAnswer = 
    { '0': { '0': true },
      '1': { '0': true, '1': false, '2': false, '3': true },
      '2': { '0': false, '1': false, '2': true}
    };
```

Comment: Changing input = not a solution.